# Ошибка при удалении элемента

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas

Я создаю div с input поверх Canvas для изменения размеров.Ошибка вылазит если я начал выделять текст в input, а отпустил кнопку за пределами Input,но в пределах wrap.Искал решение проблемы, предложили через parentNode.removeChild, но мне не помогло. Как сделать чтоб не было этой ошибки, при поведении, что начал выделять в input, а отпустил мышку за пределами input, но в пределах wrap.

сама ошибка

```
Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is no longer a child of this node. Perhaps it was moved in a 'blur' event handler?
```

Функция создания и удаления input

```
function createInput(pos, value, item) {



    const containerDiv = document.getElementById('container');

    var wrap = document.createElement('div');
    wrap.style.position = 'absolute';
    wrap.style.top = 0;
    wrap.style.left = 0;
    wrap.style.width = '100%';
    wrap.style.height = '100%';

    containerDiv.appendChild(wrap)

    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'number';

    input.style.position = 'absolute';
    input.style.top = pos.y + 3 + 'px';
    input.style.left = pos.x + 'px';

    input.style.height = 20 + 3 + 'px';
    input.style.width = 100 + 3 + 'px';
    input.value = (value + 2) * 5

    if (item.derection === 2) {
      input.onblur = (e) => dispatch(onBlurInputHorizontal({ value: e.currentTarget?.value / 5, containerDiv, wrap, itemSelect: item, width: item.width }))
    }
    else {
      input.onblur = (e) => dispatch(onBlurInputVertical({ value: e.currentTarget?.value / 5, containerDiv, wrap, itemSelect: item, height: item.height }))
    }




    wrap.appendChild(input);

    function removeInput(e) {


      if (e.target === wrap) {

        wrap.parentNode.removeChild(wrap);
        wrap.removeEventListener("click", removeInput);

      }

    }

    wrap.addEventListener('click', removeInput, { once: true });

  }
```